# Death Probabilities with differing assumptions

Tags: probability, actuarial-science

So I've just started delving into survival analysis and its varying assumptions with regards to the probabilities of dying.

A question that I have stumbled upon and would like some assistance if possible involves using the Uniform distribution of deaths, constant hazard, and the Balducci assumption.

If the probability that an individual lives from 100 years of age to 110 years of age, given that they make it to 100 is 1/1000, under each of the assumptions (UDD, constant hazard, Balducci), what proportion die on or after their 105th birthday and before their 110th birthday.

Any explanation would be great.

Comment: You can start by writing definitions of each assumption, and may be substituting known parameters into it.

Comment: I have tried this, but couldn't manage to solve it. Correct me if I'm wrong, but with the UDD assumption, the hazard rate is increasing but the number of people dying is constant per year. So the proportion who die should be approximately 50% at the halfway point. With the constant hazard assumption, I've found it resembles an exponential distribution with a constant hazard rate. Any suggestions going forward from here?

Comment: Assume we started with $1000$ people of age $100$. One of them will reach $110$. How many will reach $105$ under UDD assumption? With constant hazard, probability to survive $x$ years after $100$ is $e^{-\lambda x}$. Can you find $\lambda$ from here? And then find value for $x = 5$? (or may be even find this value directly, without first finding $\lambda$)